# Jira Subversion Mirror / SubGit remote error on push

Tags: git, svn, bitbucket, subgit

So, using Subversion mirror(SubGit) with latest BitBucket (4.8.3).  There are two changes made to master.  One made directly and one made with a merge from a feature branch.  When pushing the changes, get a SubGit error:

```
XC2T@B104315 MINGW64 /c/projects/repos/loct-demo (master)
$ git push
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: The following ref update is disallowed:
remote: error:   refs/heads/master: leads to replacement of SVN branch 'trunk'
remote: error:
remote: error: You can allow branch replacements by setting svn.allowBranchReplacement = true in SubGit configuration file.
remote: Fetching revisions from SVN repository:
remote:   up to date
remote: Sending commits to SVN repository:
To http://XC2T@localhost:7990/scm/loct/loct-demo.git 
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://XC2T@localhost:7990/scm/loct/loct-demo.git'
```

I'm sure I've done this in the past and it worked just fine.  I will try reverting back and doing this again, but just wondering if others have seen this error and know what it means.

Thanks,

Brad

Comment: Resetting git and re-doing the change seemed to solve the issue.  Just not sure why I received this issue in the first place.  Will try and reproduce with feature->commit->merge->push.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error message was introduced with SubGit version 3.2.1 and SVN Mirror add-on version 3.3.0.

SubGit/SVN Mirror rejects push operation that would result into branch replacement in Subversion repository. There are basically two cases when Git changes may lead to replacements on SVN side:

1. Force push.

   When one forcefully pushes non-fast-forward update, SubGit/SVN Mirror has nothing to do but delete current version of the branch and re-create it from some older revision, because this is exactly what non-fast-forward update does: continuing branch history from a commit other than the branch tip.
2. Fast-forward merge from one branch into another.

   When one creates a new branch `foo` from `master`:

   ```
   $ git checkout -b foo
   $ git commit -am 'fix foo'
   [foo ca3caf9] fix foo
   ```

   then pushes that branch to SubGit mirror:

   ```
   $ git push origin foo
   ...
   Sending commits to SVN repository:
     remote:   ca3caf9 => r10 branches/foo
   ```

   which gets `ca3caf9` mapped to `branches/foo@10`.

   Finally, one merges branch `foo` back to `master`:

   ```
   $ git checkout master
   $ git merge foo
   Updating 0e39ad2..ca3caf9
   Fast-forward
   ```

   Noticed that *Updating ... Fast-forward* message? It means `git merge` found no new commits on `master`, hence there was no need to create a merge commit, i.e. `git merge` just moved the `master` pointer from older commit `0e39ad2` to a newer one `ca3caf9`.

   Now what happens when one pushes `master` to SubGit mirror:

   ```
   $ git push origin master
   ```

   SubGit finds out that `master` was updated from `0e39ad2` mapped to `trunk@9` to `ca3caf9` mapped to `branches/foo@10`. There's nothing SubGit can do but delete `trunk` and re-create it from `branches/foo@10` which obviously leads to replacement of `trunk`.

And so we made sure that SubGit does not replace branches in these two scenarios unless SubGit administrator explicitly sets the following configuration option:

```
$ edit REPO/subgit/config
...
[svn]
    allowBranchReplacement = true
...
$ subgit install REPO
```

However, I'd recommend to keep `svn.allowBranchReplacement` set to `false` and follow these best practices to avoid the error message reported in the original question:

- Never force push anything; prefer to merge, revert of branch out changes rather than overwrite them.
- When merging one branch into another add `--no-ff` option: it forces `git merge` to create a merge commit when it would rather do a fast-forward update otherwise:

  ```
  $ git merge --no-ff foo
  ```

UPDATE:

If you're using SVN Mirror add-on, you can specify `svn.allowBranchReplacement` option at the *Branches Mapping* tab:

[image: Branches Mapping]

The text field should look as follows:

```
[svn]
    trunk = ...
    ...
    allowBranchReplacement = true
```

and then click on *Apply changes* button in order to activate this new setting.

Comment: I'm using the BitBucket Svn Mirror (on windows) and there doesn't seem to be any option to set this parameter in the web UI. Question 1: should I add the value into subgit\config or subgit\stash.config? question 2: I don't seem to have a subgit.exe on the server - how do I get the parameter to take effect?

Comment: @Andy you can add this option into a text field at the *Branches mapping* tab and then click on 'Apply changes' button. Please see my update for more details.